# In Powershell how do I get Select-Xml to search multiple Nodes

Tags: powershell, xml-namespaces, select-xml

So I got to say that I m new to using PowerShell for parsing out XML. With that said,  how to do I combine multiple -XPath So that I can finishing building out my expression report. Please let me know, I have tried several combinations and none of them seem to work with namespace XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" niaVersion="12.0.0.756" xmlns="http://something.com/something/hotfix/manifest">
    <releases>
        <release name="mid November 2017">
            <hotfixes>
                <hotfixref name="DE002" description="" defectSuite="n/a" supportEscalation="n/a" internalNotes="" customer="n/a">
                    <packages>
                        <package type="All" />
                    </packages>
                    <components>
                        <component type="" />
                        <component type="" />
                    </components>
                </hotfixref>
                <hotfixref name="DE5728" description="" defectSuite="DS001" supportEscalation="n/a" internalNotes="" customer="n/a">
                    <packages>
                        <package type="Full" />
                    </packages>
                    <components>
                        <component type="" />
                    </components>
                </hotfixref>
            </hotfixes>
        </release>
    </releases>
</manifest>




[xml]$xdoc=Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Manifest.xml
$ns = @{test ="http://something.com/something/hotfix/manifest"}
$ver = Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//test:release' -Namespace $ns 
$hfu = Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//test:hotfixref' -Namespace $ns 
foreach ($v in $ver){
$v | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node 
 $hfu |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty node
```

Comment: What does your XML look like? Please present us with what we need to replicate your issue. [Creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If the XML is using namespace, I don t know why would you need to see the XML. Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath works find on a single node, but all I m asking if you know of a way to combine more then one node to the Xpath please let me know.

Comment: It does help to specify the correct namespace in `$ns`. Updated question. Not sure what you mean about combine more than one node. Do you have an example of what you want (output)?

Comment: Well, it is really a request for a way for us to replicate the issue that you are seeing.

Comment: Hi EBGreen, well may I m not making my self-clear to the problem, the code I have in the upper part will work fine for a single node. meaning if I just want to see all the values for releases it will show me all the values. If I want to see all the values for the hotfixes it will show me all those values that are associated to those tags.   What I m trying to make is a  header row with the version then right below it will have the values from hotfixref ex. release value /r /n hfref DE001 blah blah blah

Comment: this is what I trying to accomplish:                                                      
 ns = @{e ='http://nexidia.com/nia/hotfix/manifest'}
$items =Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//e:release/e:hotfixref'            
  -Namespace $ns   

 Select-Object -ExpandProperty node    As you can see, I have 2 nodes in my xpath that I trying to output as part of my results. when I do this, it does not work. Now if I just left one of the nodes in there, and ran the statement I would get my result set for that node.

Comment: So you want an xpath that matches "either this or that"? But why? release is the parent of the hotfixref-nodes. Why not get release and use PowerShell to access the child nodes? See answer for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why you need to find both hotfixes and release-nodes. Release is a parent of hotfixes, so simply find all release-nodes and access its child nodes in a loop to find the relevant hotfixes. Ex:

```
$xdoc = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" niaVersion="12.0.0.756" xmlns="http://something.com/something/hotfix/manifest">
    <releases>
        <release name="mid November 2017">
            <hotfixes>
                <hotfixref name="DE002" description="" defectSuite="n/a" supportEscalation="n/a" internalNotes="" customer="n/a">
                    <packages>
                        <package type="All" />
                    </packages>
                    <components>
                        <component type="" />
                        <component type="" />
                    </components>
                </hotfixref>
                <hotfixref name="DE5728" description="" defectSuite="DS001" supportEscalation="n/a" internalNotes="" customer="n/a">
                    <packages>
                        <package type="Full" />
                    </packages>
                    <components>
                        <component type="" />
                    </components>
                </hotfixref>
            </hotfixes>
        </release>
    </releases>
</manifest>
"@



$ns = @{test ="http://something.com/something/hotfix/manifest"}
$releases = Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//test:release' -Namespace $ns  
foreach ($r in $releases){
    "$($r.node.name) contains the following hotfixes:"
    $r.node.hotfixes.hotfixref | Select-Object Name, description, defectSuite
}
```

Output:

```
mid November 2017 contains the following hotfixes:

name   description defectSuite
----   ----------- -----------
DE002              n/a
DE5728             DS001
```

If you really want one xpath-query to find both types, then use `|` (OR) to separate the xpath-queries. Ex:

```
Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//test:release|//test:hotfixref' -Namespace $ns

Node      Path        Pattern
----      ----        -------
release   InputStream //test:release|//test:hotfixref
hotfixref InputStream //test:release|//test:hotfixref
hotfixref InputStream //test:release|//test:hotfixref
```

The problem with this is that you will need logic to detect what type of node you're accessing since it may be release or it may be `hotfixref`. You will also need extra logic to understand which `hotfixref` belongs to which release.

Comment: Thank you, I came up with the same conclusion last night here is a snippet of what I wrote:                                                                         ` foreach( $n in $ns){
$items =Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//e:release' -Namespace $n 
$items1 =Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -XPath '//e:hotfixref' -Namespace $n 
}
$values += $items + $items1 
 $values | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node | select  name, description  `

Comment: I must say I was on the right path, but again working with PowerShell and XML  is kind of new to me. Most of the stuff I do write involves search logs and building other  tools for troubleshooting issues.

Comment: You'll get there. I didn't understand why you would loop `$ns`. It won't work because it's a hashtable and you only had one namespace in there so there's no need for a loop

Comment: If you ever need a script that will search for "select string" that will build a unc path, will search any remote server no matter what the drive letter is and find the pattern you are looking for in logs.  I have that.